# Fill frame wxpython

Tags: python, window, wxpython, panel, expand

I am creating a GUI in wxpython, and am encountering a problem which I cannot wrap my head around. All panels and labels are using wx.ENABLED and 1 as proportion, but still it won't maximize my panels to the window. I assume that I must at least be able to stretch them horizontally.

Frame:

```
import wx

class MyFrame2 ( wx.Frame ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 500,300 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

        self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )

        winSizer = wx.FlexGridSizer( 1, 2, 0, 0 )
        winSizer.SetFlexibleDirection( wx.BOTH )
        winSizer.SetNonFlexibleGrowMode( wx.FLEX_GROWMODE_SPECIFIED )

        self.leftPanel = wx.Panel( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        gSizer6 = wx.GridSizer( 2, 1, 0, 0 )

        self.someInput = wx.TextCtrl( self.leftPanel, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        gSizer6.Add( self.someInput, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )

        self.leftButton = wx.Button( self.leftPanel, wx.ID_ANY, u"MyButton", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        gSizer6.Add( self.leftButton, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )


        self.leftPanel.SetSizer( gSizer6 )
        self.leftPanel.Layout()
        gSizer6.Fit( self.leftPanel )
        winSizer.Add( self.leftPanel, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )

        self.rightPanel = wx.Panel( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        fgSizer14 = wx.FlexGridSizer( 2, 1, 0, 0 )
        fgSizer14.SetFlexibleDirection( wx.BOTH )
        fgSizer14.SetNonFlexibleGrowMode( wx.FLEX_GROWMODE_SPECIFIED )

        self.innerPanel = wx.Panel( self.rightPanel, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        gSizer8 = wx.GridSizer( 0, 2, 0, 0 )

        self.someText = wx.StaticText( self.innerPanel, wx.ID_ANY, u"Bla bla", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.someText.Wrap( -1 )
        gSizer8.Add( self.someText, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )


        self.innerPanel.SetSizer( gSizer8 )
        self.innerPanel.Layout()
        gSizer8.Fit( self.innerPanel )
        fgSizer14.Add( self.innerPanel, 1, wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.rightButton = wx.Button( self.rightPanel, wx.ID_ANY, u"MyButton", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        fgSizer14.Add( self.rightButton, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )


        self.rightPanel.SetSizer( fgSizer14 )
        self.rightPanel.Layout()
        fgSizer14.Fit( self.rightPanel )
        winSizer.Add( self.rightPanel, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )


        self.SetSizer( winSizer )
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

    def __del__( self ):
        pass
```

When opening the window as maximized:

[image: maximized]

When opening the window as minimized:

[image: minimized]

Why does it work when I minimize the window and not working with maximized windows? All attributes are stretched and expanded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that `FlexGridSizer` has two properties named `growablerows`and `growablecols`.
These properties take a list of indices that indicates which rows and/or columns that should be able to be expanded, which made the trick.

If no rows/cols are specifilaly set as growable, FlexGridSizer will always pack all elements as tight as possible.

Comment: Have to wait two days before I can accept it, but will do that when I can :)